# Docker and MATLAB

Tags: ros, matlab, docker

I am running my roscore from MATLAB using rosinit and the ROS_IP was set '127.0.0.1', this creates a ROS Master at 'http://127.0.0.1:11311'. I am running ROS within a docker container running on the same host.

I am also using `--net=host` to use the host network configurations directly. However, whenever I try to initialize a node in the docker container I get the following error message:

```
Unable to register with master node [http://127.0.0.1:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--ipc=host` to your docker run command. 
Now, the process inside the Docker container and the host will have have same IPC(Inter-Process communication) namespace. This is required when process inside the container need to communicate with process outside the container.